# Backbone ReferenceError

Tags: backbone.js

I have Backbone view that looks like this:

```
App.Views.HistoricalDataSelector = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function (options) {
    this.template = JST['backbone/templates/historical_data_selector'];
    this.collection = options.collection;
    this.model = options.model;
    this.render();
  },

  myCollection: function() {
    return this.collection.byReportType(this.model.get('report_type')).byReportOrganizationType(this.model.get('report_organization_type'))
  },

  render: function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template({
      collection: myCollection,
      model: this.model
    }));
  }
});
```

when I try to render it Backbone returns me the following error:

```
ReferenceError: myCollection is not defined
```

But when I change render method to this:

```
  render: function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template({
      collection: this.collection.byReportType(this.model.get('report_type')).byReportOrganizationType(this.model.get('report_organization_type')),
      model: this.model
    }));
  }
```

why he can't find this myCollection method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot the `this` keyword, and probably also to invoke the method:

```
render: function () {
 this.$el.html(this.template({
  collection: this.myCollection(),
  //-----------^ view reference ^---- function invocation ------
  model: this.model
 }));
}
```